# jQuery submit form and get response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a webpage that will submit a form and redirect to another page. Is there a way to do this through jQuery, and get the response page in a callback function? So that the page won't redirect and I can show a message from the server in the same page.

I have tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
$('#reset-password-form').submit(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    return false;
});
```

Also I tried following code snippet, which also didn't work:

```
$('#reset-password-form').submit(function(data){
    $.ajax({
        url: window.location.href,
        // contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
        cache: false,
        // contentType: 'text/html',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        // processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data : $('#reset-password-form').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            console.log('form submitted.');
        },
        error:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            console.log('form error.');
        },
        failure: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            console.log('form submit failed.');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Please advise.

#### Adding HTML Section:

```
<form id="reset-password-form">
   <div data-message-bar="">

   </div>
   <input type="hidden" name="username" value="dummy">
   <input type="hidden" name="validationToken" value="248gf293g2793g273f972">
   <input required="" name="password" type="password">
   <input required="" name="passwordconfirm" type="password">
   <button data-action="reset-password">Reset Password</button>
</form>
```

Comment: @hasan No, that is totally incorrect. The best way to intercept a form submission is through the `onSubmit` event. OP's `return false` at the end of the event listener will prevent form submission.

Comment: Without any more information, it is difficult to diagnose why your AJAX request is not working. Here are some steps that will help, and you can always update your question with more information. (1) Is the endpoint called correct (i.e. the URL being called is valid)? (2) What is the response from the server? Check your browser's networking tab. (3) What is the backend code that receives the data? Are you sure it is accepting `POST` requests?

Comment: @Terry i thought that backend works correctly and error is page reload, in my opinion Kharkoza can use ajax in button on("click")

Comment: @Terry & hasan: 
(1) Is the endpoint called correct (i.e. the URL being called is valid)?
YES, If I kept my form as it is without any jQuery handler and with form attribute method="post", its submitting the form and reloading (with out any action action attribute). I am using window.location.href


(2) What is the response from the server? 
A JSON object, without any error information. I have checked in the network tab. Its not coming into my jQuery code. I want the same page which is coming as part of usual form submit in jQuery call.

(3) Backed is accepting post method.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? The success and error callbacks are deprecated in v3 and replaced by done and fail

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```js
 <button id="resetpass" data-action="reset-password">Reset Password</button>
$("#resetpass").on("click", function(event){
    $.ajax({
            url: window.location.href,
            // contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
            cache: false,
            // contentType: 'text/html',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            // processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            data : $('#reset-password-form').serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                console.log('form submitted.');
            },
            error:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                console.log('form error.');
            },
            failure: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                console.log('form submit failed.');
            }
        });

})
```

Comment: But I am not getting the HTML page response!!

Comment: How is that different from adding `return false;` at the end?

Comment: I think the best way calling ajax without form submit, @KharkoozaBoche can use button id with on("click") to use ajax

Comment: After this also, page is reloading.

Comment: are you sure? because this dont submit form, trigger when normal button click and runs just jquery ajax

Answer (score 0):

Do not return anything, returning false ll quit form submission

```
<form onSubmit="formSubmit()" id="reset-password-form">
   <div data-message-bar="">

   </div>
   <input type="hidden" name="username" value="dummy">
   <input type="hidden" name="validationToken" value="248gf293g2793g273f972">
   <input required="" name="password" type="password">
   <input required="" name="passwordconfirm" type="password">
   <button data-action="reset-password">Reset Password</button>
</form>

function formSubmit(){
    $.ajax({
            url: window.location.href,
            // contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
            cache: false,
            // contentType: 'text/html',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            // processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            data : $('#reset-password-form').serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                console.log('form submitted.');
            },
            error:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                console.log('form error.');
            },
            failure: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                console.log('form submit failed.');
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: When I am removing the `return false`, page is reloading. I don't want to reload the page.

Comment: do not use form submit. call the above function instead.

Comment: you can try onSubmit.

Comment: Its still redirecting.

Comment: that is because your form is submitting .

Comment: can you add the html part?

Comment: Added html section

Comment: I have checked network tab, form is getting submitted only one time. JS function is also getting executed one time.

Comment: make sure you have set the routes properly on server side

Comment: check url that you are sending the post request.
    url:window.location.href..??

Answer (score 0):

remove `data` from function and do not return false

```
$(document).on('submit', '#reset-password-form',function(e){
   $.ajax({
        url: window.location.href,
        // contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
        cache: false,
        // contentType: 'text/html',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        // processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data : $('#reset-password-form').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            console.log('form submitted.');
        },
        error:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            console.log('form error.');
        },
        failure: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            console.log('form submit failed.');
        }
    })
    .done(function(){
         alert("Done");
         $('#reset-password-form')[0].reset();
    });
    e.preventdefault(); // stop page refresh
 });
```

Comment: But I am not getting the HTML page response!!

Comment: which response do you want. you can use `.done(function(res){ alert(res); })`

Comment: If I kept my form as it is without any jQuery handler and with form attribute method="post", its submitting the form and reloading (with out any action action attribute). Thats why I am using window.location.href

Comment: @KharkoozaBoche I have edited the code. check it again. If it does not work as you need please clear what do you exactly need.